# Explanation of Fibonacci tail recursion in scheme?

Tags: scheme, fibonacci

I have been trying to understand tail recursion in Scheme and I am having a hard time understanding what is happening in the go to example using tail recursion for Fibonacci...

if this is the code for tail recursion, or iterative Fibonacci:

```
(define (fib n)
  (fib-iter 1 0 n))

(define (fib-iter a b count)
  (if (= count 0)
    b
    (fib-iter (+ a b) a (- count 1))))
```

I can essentially understand what is happening on every line except for here:

```
(fib-iter 1 0 n))
```

what is actually happening in this line?  I can't find an explanation anywhere.  I'm new to Scheme and the syntax is pretty confusing so far.

Or can anyone explain what is happening in each line?  this is my basic understanding but I am unsure if I am correct:

```
(define (fib n) ;;define the function fib and variable n
  (fib-iter 1 0 n)) ;;?? no idea

(define (fib-iter a b count) ;;define function fib-iter, variables a, b and count
  (if (= count 0) ;;if the count is equal to 0, 
    b ;;return b
    (fib-iter (+ a b) a (- count 1)))) ;;recursively calling function fib-iter with 3 parameters (a+b), a and (count - 1)
```

thanks!

Comment: "(define (fib n) ;define the function fib and variable n" not quite so -- this *defines the function `fib` which takes one parameter called `n`*. similarly, `(define (fib-iter ...` defines the function `fib-iter` which takes 3 parameters, 1st named `a`, 2nd-`b` and 3rd-`count`. To visualize how tail-recursion works, draw two horizontal lines, above and below the form `(fib-iter a b count)`. What you get is a *frame* - a named box with three slots (in this case). Then each call `(fib-iter x y z)` just puts the three values `x y z` into the three slots of the frame, and (re)starts its execution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a typo in the `fib` procedure (an opening parentheses is missing), it should be defined as follows:

```
(define (fib n)
  (fib-iter 1 0 n))
```

Having said that, the iterative `fib` procedure uses a helper called `fib-iter` for implementing the actual iteration. This line:

```
(fib-iter 1 0 n)
```

Is simply calling the helper for the first time. As you know, the fibonacci series starts with the values `0` for `n=0` and `1` for `n=1`, and that's precisely the values that we're passing as parameters, to start the iteration loop, together with the value of `n` which is the number of iterations we want to do before stopping.

From that point on, `a` will contain the value of fibonacci for `n-1` and `b` will contain the value of fibonacci for `n-2`, and each successive step in the iteration takes care of updating the `a` and `b` variables accordingly, until `n` is zero, and at this point we stop and return the result.

It might be easier to picture what's happening if we write the same algorithm in an imperative style. Here's one example in Python using an explicit looping construct and the same variable names. This is equivalent to the Scheme implementation:

```
def fib(n):
    count = n
    a, b = 1, 0
    while count != 0:
        a, b = a + b, a
        count = count - 1
    return b
```

Comment: I don't understand why it wouldn't be (fib-iter 0 1 n)

Comment: Thank you so much!  I can finally wrap me head around it

Comment: @Sarah It would be if `fib-iter` were written a little differently, such as `(if (zero? count) a (fib-iter b (+ a b) (- count 1)))`. But in your case, the roles of `a` and `b` were swapped from their conventional meanings.

Answer (score 2):

There's an error in your code; `fib` should be a procedure:

```
(define (fib n)
  (fib-iter 1 0 n))
```

What is does is it calls `fib-iter` with the initial values of a(=1), b(=0) and count(=the fibonacci number you want, which is the formal parameter `n` to `fib`).

Adding a print 'statement' to `fib-iter` shows what happens, in this example for `(fib 7)`:

```
a=1  b=0  count=7 ; initial values as given by `fib`
a=1  b=1  count=6
a=2  b=1  count=5
a=3  b=2  count=4
a=5  b=3  count=3
a=8  b=5  count=2
a=13  b=8  count=1
a=21  b=13  count=0
13 ; the returned value for `(fib 7)`
```